# How can I view a log of all recent deployments to a specific environment?

Tags: octopus-deploy

I want to know what deployments have recently occurred on my QA environment.  It comprises several servers and several projects, so I don't want to go trawling through each environment separately or each project separately.

I tried clicking on the QA environment header on the home page, but it just takes me to the list of all environments - no links/buttons to logs for a specific environment.

Version: `Octopus Deploy 2.6.4.951`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the filtering on the 'Tasks' page.  Looks like filtering was introduced in 2.5. https://octopus.com/blog/2.5#organised-task-page-including-filtering

/Octopus/app#/tasks

There are filters for Environment (QA) and 'Task Type' (Deployment).  Checking mine just showed me all the deployments to QA and that there is one waiting approval.

Answer (score 0):

I also filter the tasks page, but also have a PowerBI project which queries the API on the below URL:

http://octopus.example.com/api/reporting/deployments/xml?apikey=API-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY

This can then set up whatever you want :)